# Horizontal ::after line/bar displaying after paragraph, not header

Tags: html, css

I created a horizontal line/bar beneath my `h1` headers, but on this particular header, it displays the line beneath the header's `p` subtext instead of directly underneath the header

I tried wrapping the header in a div, but the line still displays beneath the `p` subtext, not the header

```css
.header-text {
    font-size: 45px;
    text-align: center;
}

.header-text::after {
    content: '';
    width: 70px;
    height: 2px;
    background: #3FA9F5;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -10px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.header-subtext {
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="field field--name-body field--type-text-with-summary field--label-hidden field--item">

<h1 class="header-text">Header text</h1>

<p class="header-subtext">Testing 123 abc fghijkl.</p>

</div>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ykk3l.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you have positioned the pseudo element as `absolute`, and its parent has none.

You're missing this:

```
.header-text {
  position: relative;
}
```

```css
.header-text {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 45px;
    text-align: center;
}

.header-text::after {
    content: '';
    width: 70px;
    height: 2px;
    background: lime;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -10px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.header-subtext {
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1 class="header-text">Header text</h1>
  <p class="header-subtext">Testing 123 abc fghijkl.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: @joe glad i could help